# What's the use of IsolationLevel in SqlTransaction if I never get to read volatile data from one transaction in another?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, transactions

I'm studying data access in .NET Framework 4 for a Microsoft Certification and I've been doing a lot of tests.

This time I want to understand the purpose of `IsolationLevel` in the `SqlTransaction` class. As I understand, this option allows me to decide whether or not, volatile data in one transaction is accessible by another one. That is, for instance: I create a data row in Transaction 1 and, before commiting it, I can read the data in Transaction 2.

The fact is that I can't get to read volatile data from one in another.

- If I create **1 connection** with **2 transactions** I get an exception because SQL Server does not support parallel transactions
- If I create **2 connections** with **1 transaction** each, no matter the value of IsolationLevel, the program stops when I try to access data in connection 2 while connection 1 is in transaction. As connection 1 leaves the transaction, the program continues.

So.. **What's the use of IsolationLevel?**

PS: I'm not talking about distributed transactions here, just the simple SqlTransaction.

Comment: "no matter the value of IsolationLevel" - doesn't sound correct. Have you used READ UNCOMMITED?

Comment: @Mitch: Yes, ReadUncommited is the lowest isolation level and yet the thread stops

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need **2 connections**, **2 transactions**, on **2 threads**.

thread 1:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection())
{
  using (SqlTransaction trn = conn.BeginTransaction())
  {
    -- insert row into table here, then wait
  }
}
```

thread 2:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = GetSqlConnection())
{
  using (SqlTransaction trn = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.<desiredlevel>))
  {
    -- wait for thread 1 to insert then read row inserted by thread 1 
  }
}
```

Under `ReadUncommited` the second thread will read the row. Under `Snapshot` (if Snapshot is enabled in the database) it will not see it, but it won't block. Under all other isolation levels it will block until the thread 1 commits or rolls back.

Comment: Definitely great answer. Thank you Remus. I though that the IsolationLevel of one transaction would determine how it's own volatile data were exposed to the rest of the world. By your example I assume the the IsolationLevel of one transaction determines how it accesses volatile data in the rest of the world.

Comment: @Andre: it is a bit more complicated. For dirty read, read committed and snapshot it is true that the isolation level applies to 'How does my transaction see the world?'. But once you consider the `RepeatableRead` and `Serializable` levels, the isolation levels start meaning 'How can others change my world?'. Under repeatable read other cannot change anything I looked at (once I touch it, it will always be there, unchanged, until I commit), but other may insert *new* stuff in my world. Under `Serializable` nobody can modify what I seen, but also nobody can *insert* new stuff in my world.

Comment: And going by the same metaphor the `Snapshot` isolation means 'My world has frozen when I started my transaction'. Although the real world does change, I'm stuck in time and I always see the world *as it was* when I started my snapshot transaction (I see a *snapshot* of the world). Of course, I see my *own* changes in this snapshot.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a helpful explanation. I think it's clearer now.

Comment: Great answer. But it is not clear to me what "but can be modified" means in IsolationLevel.ReadCommited. Does that mean that in Thread2 I can change data added by Thread1, but can`t read the data from Thread1 until it commits? Plus does ReadCommited also mean that new data can be added during the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Conn_String);
    conn.Open();

    SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_user_master set page_state=1", conn);

    cmd.Transaction = trans;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    call(trans, conn);

    trans.Commit();

}

public void call(SqlTransaction trans, SqlConnection conn)
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_user_master set page_state=0", conn);
    cmd.Transaction = trans;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

This is used in case you have multiple functions with 1 SQL transaction