# Backup original row data before committing transaction to SQL Server using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, transactions, rollback

I want to be able to backup all original data for the rows in a table that have been modified or deleted. I also want to keep track of all the inserted rows. The reason for this is that my application will have a user on it to alter changes to a database, and I do not want to commit the changes until the user confirms that all the changes are correct.

How would I go about doing this? I took a look at the TransactionScope and Transaction classes, but what if the program has 100 updates to do to 100 different tables. If my understanding is correct, then I would require 100 different threads until the user confirms that the changes are correct? I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657033/whats-the-use-of-isolationlevel-in-sqltransaction-if-i-never-get-to-read-volati) when searching about committing and rolling back transactions.

Help :(

Comment: Why not store the changes until the user confirms rather than make the changes and rollback if the user doesn't confirm?

Comment: You said: _"I want to be able to backup all original data for the rows in a table that have been modified or deleted."_.  What is the anticipated lifespan of these 'backup' records?

Comment: I think you are taking a fundamentally incorrect approach. You should keep track of the changes the user wants to make, and only write them to the database (inside of a transaction, of course) once the user has confirmed them. You can use an OR/M such as EntityFramework to do this, or you could use something like the `DataTable` class which has an `AcceptChanges` and `GetChanges` method. You would only call `AcceptChanges` once the user has decided to commit their updates.

Comment: Because I want to store the original in a file just in case later on, they realize it was in error. The primary reason is to prevent application\user error, and the secondary reason is to have a backup in case of logical\design error...

Comment: Lifespan of the backups are anywhere from an hour to two weeks. **Usually** it is only between 1-50 rows of data for a particular customer.

Comment: Well, the changes to the database are made by support personal who do not directly know every inner working of our legacy program we are going to re-write. My company's policy right now, technically, is backup the entire database before any changes are made.

Comment: As far as I understand you want to track all the changes in a table, allowing a person edit and another person commit the changes. Is that right?

Comment: It would be the same person committing the changes, but yes only the changes, I don't need a whole table backed up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're waiting for user input you shouldn't leave a transaction open the whole time.  Transactions are better suited to handling low level rollbacks within the database itself or from .NET code managing database operations.

If you're waiting for user input, store the temporary data in a different table until you have confirmation from them and then move the data to its ultimate location.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to track all changed rows your issue is not about Transaction. Transaction is for keeping integrity of database incase of an error between two commands. I think you need an Undo/Redo history model.

You can solve your problem by using additional tables. One table for keeping all changes and one for pointing approved version of changes. For a products table it may be something like that:

```
Products Table
RowId | ProductId | ProductName | Description | Price | ChangingTime

ApprovedProducts Table
ProductId | RowId
```

Whenever user updates a product you add a new row into `Products` table and you can point the desired row with `RowId` in `ApprovedProducts` table.

Comment: I like the idea... but I still have no idea how to implement it. How do I detect which rows are being modified\inserted if I send UPDATE\INSERT\DELETE commands through SqlCommand. My first guess would be to parse the command, then generate a query for the modified\inserted row and save the data to the table? ... However parsing SQL commands is difficult :-(

Comment: Whenever you modify a product you will add the modified one (or the new one if its new) to the Products table. So actually You will never send UPDATE or DELETE command for Products table. You will only INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should leave to the database to do it, you can write a trigger on insert, update and delete and save the new data and old data. do this on front end is no recomended, triggers are easy and portable to any data base engine.

Regards,